# booking app and account deletion

Tags: usability, web-app

I am building a booking app where regular users will be able to make bookings for business users. Regular users will connect to the frontend of the site and business users to the backend where they will see the boookings made by regular users.Business users will be able to make bookings also for regular users via the phone and not the web. As such the app from a business user point of view will hold bookings made by the web and also bookings made via the phone(the latter will be stored to the app by the b.user manually)

My question has to do with how to deal account deletion of a business user **and in case there are bookings aoutstanding.**

Should I warn him that he is about to delete all the bookings if he chooses to delete the account and do so if he wants to proceed deleting the account?

Or for example I should give him/her the option of(for example) downloading all the bookings in a PDF form and also delete all the bookings in the db?

How about saying him that the account will be deleted permanently when there are no more bookings pending?

I think this last option is impractical for various reasons.

Anyway, what do you propose?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. I'd assume `regular users` are people outside the business, and `business users` are employes of the business. So a sentences like "regular users will make bookings for business users" or "deletion of a business user". And who will be deleting business users?

Comment: Υour assumption is correct as to what regular users and business users are.Business will be deleted only by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it depends on how big of a deal it is to cancel the bookings.

If there are no significant side effects to canceling all of the bookings, the first option is the best.

If canceling a booking is a big deal, then I would suggest simply giving a message saying "you can't close your account while bookings are outstanding".  The user would then have to go and individually cancel the bookings before closing the account.

Providing a PDF of outstanding bookings is not necessary--if the user wants information from you, they should just keep their account open.  They are the one choosing not to do business with you any more, so you don't have a responsibility to continue to provide services to them.

Delayed account closure would be hard to program, and also confusing.  It raises all sorts of edge cases that might have to be handled.